# Notify only when file copying is completed: Node js

Tags: node.js

I have this node js code which monitors the file changes.

```
fsmonitor = require('fsmonitor');
fsmonitor.watch('path\to\files', null, function(change) {
    console.log("Change detected:\n" + change); 
    console.log("Added files:    %j", change.addedFiles);
    console.log("Modified files: %j", change.modifiedFiles);
    console.log("Removed files:  %j", change.removedFiles);

    console.log("Added folders:    %j", change.addedFolders);
    console.log("Modified folders: %j", change.modifiedFolders);
    console.log("Removed folders:  %j", change.removedFolders);
});

var monitor = fsmonitor.watch('.', {
    // include files
    matches: function(relpath) {
        return relpath.match(/\.js$/i) !== null;
    },
    // exclude directories
    excludes: function(relpath) {
        return relpath.match(/^\.git$/i) !== null;
    }
});
monitor.on('change', function(changes) {
    console.log(changes);
});
```

However, if I copy a 1GB file (it takes some time to copy) it triggers the change both at the moment I copy it and finish copying. How can I notify the change only when the copying is fully completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
monitor.on('complete', function(changes) {
    console.log(changes);
});
```

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/andreyvit/fsmonitor.js/blob/master/lib/monitor.iced) check line 14.

```
@tree.once 'complete', @_finishInitialization.bind(@)
```

Not sure if this will do it, but it would be my first guess.

UPDATE:

I would do this instead.

Use https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar which fsmonitor.js repo points to as a better alternative. Read the documentation on `awaitWriteFinish`. This seems more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But it gives the same results.

Comment: Check my update. I think you want to use the chokidar library instead. fsmonitor.js states that it is a better alternative since it is actually being maintained.

Comment: Yes.. it worked when it comes to triggering the upload completion. But still, it shows as a change in the file instead of adding a new file.

Comment: You didn't say anything about uploads. Is that what you are using this for? I think the better use case for this is if a file is changing on the server without being a direct upload. If you are receiving an uploaded file there would be better ways to know when the file upload is complete. What sort of server are you using to receive the file? Node js?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's file copying not uploading.